# HTML form input errors PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

```
            <form action="index.php" name="Submit_Form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload" class="upload">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Upload</legend><br/>
            Title:  <input type="text" name="title" id="name" class="name" required> <br/><br/>
            <textarea name="description" rows="6" cols="35" maxlength="120"></textarea><br/>
            <input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" required multiple><br/>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
        </fieldset> 


        <div class="bar">
            <span class="bar-fill" id="pb"><span class="bar-fill-text" id="pt"></span></span>
        </div>

        <div id="uploads" class="uploads"> 
        Uploaded file links will appear here.   
        </div>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['title'])) {
$title = $_POST['title'];
}

if (isset($_POST['description'])) {
$description = $_POST['description'];
}

$dbhost     = "localhost";

$dbname     = "blog";

$dbuser     = "root";

$dbpass     = "";



// database connection

$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);


// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// query

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO videos (title,description) VALUES (?,?)");

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $title, $description);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
 ?> 

 <script src="upload.js"></script>
        <script>

            document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var f = document.getElementById('file'),
                    pb = document.getElementById('pb'),
                    pt = document.getElementById('pt');


                    blog.uploader({
                    files: f,
                    progressBar: pb,
                    progressText: pt,
                    processor: 'uploads.php',

                    finished: function(data) {
                        var uploads = document.getElementById('uploads'),
                        succeeded = document.createElement('div'),
                        failed = document.createElement('div'),

                        anchor,
                        span,
                        x;

                    if(data.failed.length) {
                        failed.innerHTML = '<p>This item failed to upload:</p>';
                    }

                    uploads.textContent = '';

                    for(x = 0; x < data.succeeded.length; x = x + 1) {
                        anchor = document.createElement('a');
                        anchor.href = 'uploads/' + data.succeeded[x].file;
                        anchor.textContent = data.succeeded[x].name;
                        anchor.target = '_blank';

                        succeeded.appendChild(anchor);  
                    }

                    for(x = 0; x < data.failed.length; x = x + 1) {
                        span = document.createElement('span');
                        span.textContent = data.failed[x].name;

                        failed.appendChild(span);

                    }
                    uploads.appendChild(succeeded);
                    upload.appendChild(failed);
                },

                    error: function() {
                        console.log('Not working'); 
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I talked to 'PHP expert' for hours, he couldn't seem to figure out my problem. My inputs aren't submitting to my db, title/description. I can use

```
$title = $_POST['dsfasfddsfa'];
```

and it will insert that, but I can't insert what users enter into the field. When I added

```
$title = $_POST['title']; & $description = $_POST['description'];
```

I get unidentified index on title and description, that's why I added the if statements at the top of my php code.

I read on a website it was suppose to remove them, I thought it'd work once they were gone, I was wrong. Nothing worked when I did that. I can get the video to upload, but the fields don't work. Any and all help is great! Thanks in advance.I also used submit as the $_POST in the two if statements at the start if the php code, didn't work.

Comment: Where is your closing `</form>` element?

Comment: Try adding `print_r($_POST);` to debug all POST variables. See if title and description are even in the array.

Comment: No, I'm assuming it's not, it just says Array() :| Not sure how to fix that though, & my ending tag is there, just didn't get it copied in with this.

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` would only work after submitting the form...

Comment: Also, just my 2 cents, but you should put the form processing at the top of the page.

Comment: I added it and that's what came up once I refreshed, it's also the same after uploading..

Comment: Maybe post the all of the code so we can test it out. Nothing looks off at first glance.

Comment: There it is, the other page is just a page that handles what's allowed. I've also tried posting my php script below the form tag and it still didn't work, the guy on CodeMentor said it's fine, but he was stuck. I also talked to someone else and he said I'm missing simple concepts, but he didn't want to help for free and encouraged me to find out on my own, but no one I've talked to seems to spot anything!

Comment: what would `$title = $_POST['dsfasfddsfa'];` insert? going from the code you have posted that line would insert null as i can not find a field in your from named `dsfasfddsfa`. also may i suggest that with `$title` and `$description` you assign them values before your `if(isset(` lines that way you can see wether or not that they are being re-assigned the new values (if they are not then it's because your `isset` lines is stopping them)

Comment: I actually changed that, I typed it out and copied it to this site and then fixed it and tried it. I didn't write that, it was more like `$title = 'sdfsfas'` and that posted that to the db, sorry.

Comment: I tested your code and the POST vars come through correctly for me ...

Comment: @David try doing `var_dump` to see your `$_POST`, it appears your `isset`s are returning false

Comment: This is what I got when I deleted everything like the answered below https://gyazo.com/70dec7a976ca1deb7c9a712819550d30

Comment: @David you are trying to insert 3 values with an insert query which only specifies 2 table fields. the third value is blank

Comment: @Memor-X what do you mean? I'm only trying to insert the title and description..

Comment: @David according to your screenshot your not, the SQL error shows you are trying to insert a third blank value ('fad','dfads',**''**)

Comment: @Memor-X I don't understand that, maybe I was trying upload the video? Which wasn't defined anywhere, but I removed the video input and it still gave me that

Comment: @David your query that you appear to be using [in your screenshot](https://gyazo.com/70dec7a976ca1deb7c9a712819550d30) is `INSERT INTO video (title,description) VALUES('fad','dafds','')` this is producing the SQL error as you are saying you are inserting 3 values into 2 table fields. where is the third empty string supposed to go?. after you get this erro fixed up i suggest doing `var_dump` on `$_POST` and screenshot that so one can see why your `isset()` is returning false

Comment: I don't see how I could fix that, when it's not like that. :/ https://gyazo.com/7ae3e08f3df6585dfd7fafbc1a29d8aa Same as above. Ughhhh D:

Comment: @David is that screenshot you just posted the code you are using in your previous screenshot? the one generating the SQL Error that i am point out?

Comment: @Memor-X Yessir. The same code as above

Answer (score 0):

Try to do an simple version david like in this example first.

[http://php.net/manual/es/tutorial.forms.php](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
<p>Your name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
 <p>Your age: <input type="text" name="age" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

.

```
Hi <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>.
You are <?php echo (int)$_POST['age']; ?> years old.
```

Then later step by step you will change the things that you want.

At the end will be working.